# Reusing a template page in Spring MVC

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, template-engine

What is the best and easiest technology from the followings?

Tiles, velocity or freemaker?

Thank you.

Comment: "best" and "easiest" are good words to get your question ignored and/or closed. Please ask a more specific question.

Comment: Thanks! I wanted to know that which one of these technologies is more flexible in using and handling them....?????????

Which one has more advantages in using them? What is most likely to be helping a template to work as a masterpage( as in .net) ??

plz help....

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's no "best", but it's good to know that JSP as being a view technology already provides the [`<jsp:include>`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/syntax/2.0/syntaxref2020.html#8828) tag for this. E.g.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>SO question 2158749</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <jsp:include page="menu.jsp" />
        <h1>Content</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

where in you can just code `menu.jsp` as if it's a part of the parent page:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="faq">FAQ</a></li>
    <li><a href="content">Content</a></li>
</ul>
```

There are two "standard" alternatives: the [`@include`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/syntax/2.0/syntaxref209.html#1003408) directive and the JSTL [`<c:import>`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/import.html) tag.

The difference is that the `@include` directive includes the page during **compile time** (thus it will happen only once), while the `<jsp:include>` includes the page during **runtime** (which has actually the benefit that you can include another dynamic content).

Further is the difference of `<c:import>` that it includes the **generated output** of the page and thus not the **source code** as both `<jsp:include>` and `@include` does. The major benefit of `<c:import>` is however that you can include *external* resources this way. E.g.

```
<c:import url="http://google.com" />
```